# c++ class implementing interface, interface has method taking any class implementing that interface

Tags: c++, interface

I'm implementing my own linked list in C++. The code below is for the iterator part of the linked list.

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    virtual bool operator== (const Iterator &rhs) const = 0;
};

class LinkedListIterator : public Iterator
{
public:
    int fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas;

    bool operator== (const Iterator &rhs) const
    {
        return fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas == rhs.fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas;
    }
};
```

I want to have an `Iterator` interface with some common methods that many (future) iterators can implement too.

From the code, as you can guess, the `rhs` variable does not have that field, so the code won't compile. But what should I change it to? This code doesn't work either:

```
bool operator== (const Iterator &rhs) const
{
    LinkedListIterator &rhs2 = (LinkedListIterator)rhs;

    return fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas == rhs2.fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas;
}
```

Neither does this:

```
bool operator== (const LinkedListIterator &rhs) const
{
    return fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas == rhs.fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas;
}
```

Since then the `LinkedListIterator` class is abstract.

To solve this in Java I would have used `instanceof` but how to do it in C++?

Comment: If the `fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas` belongs only to the specific `LinkedListIterator` class, then your comparator can't be generic. The last code snippet should work. what is the compile error?

Comment: @NirMH It compiles with the last snippet, but then `LinkedListIterator` is an abstract class, which I don't want it to be.

Comment: How the `LinkedListIterator` becomes abstracted?

Comment: @NirMH I suppose it is because `Iterator` requires an `Iterator` argument while, in the last case, the `LinkedListImplementation` doesn't implement such a method. Only a method that takes a `LinkedListIterator` argument. If I try to intantiate a `LinkedListIterator` in that case Visual Studio gives me "cannot instantiate abstract class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dynamic_cast<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) would give the most equivalent functionality to Java instanceof. This requires that the compiler has [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) enabled.

Though, needing to use dynamic_cast<> is usually a sign that the design could be improved.

```
bool operator== (const Iterator &rhs) const
{
    const LinkedListIterator *rhs2 = dynamic_cast<const LinkedListIterator *>(&rhs);
    if (rhs2) {
        return fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas == rhs2->fieldOnlyLinkedListIteratorHas;
    }
    return false; // Is not an instance of LinkedListIterator, therefore must be !=.
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works as expected! Regarding the design, it is perhaps not good C++ style to have an interface like this for `Iterator`? Should I ditch the interface or do another change to improve the design?

Comment: Good C++ style would be to use the built in STL linked list and iterators. :) Beyond that, if you really want to implement these classes yourself as a training excercise, I would at least have a look at the STL containers/iterators and how they are designed.